# Как запустить python файл из python файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу запустить отдельно новый python файл
Я пробовал использовать

```
   os.system(r'С:\browser\web.py')
   os.startfile(r'С:\browser\web.py')
```

Но файл просто открывается у меня в текстовом редакторе.
Я не хочу создавать exe файл так как я хочу иметь возможность редактировать файл, а уже потом давать другим пользователям его использовать без каких либо спец программ.

Comment: Ну что-нибудь типа `'python С:\browser\web.py'`, возможно, питону нужно полный путь и расширение указать. Ну либо пропишите в винде дефолтным приложением для `.py` файлов опять же интерпретатор питона, сейчас там видимо редактор прописан.

Comment: @CrazyElf `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] ═х єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ Їрщы: 'python С:\browser\web.py'` Менять дефолтное приложение в винде не вариант.

Comment: Ну значит пробуйте полный путь к питону указать, как к скрипту указали